# MySQL time interval query returning empty set but I can see the data

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[Table data screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9L9MJ.png)

Basically, I want to get the all active/suspended profiles using the query:

```
SELECT * FROM q_lab.auto_profile_status_log WHERE apsl_timestamp = NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

But the result is an empty set! I know I'm missing something but I can't figure it out.

Update: [These don't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YibNT.png)

Comment: use CURDATE()  instead of now  If you are only interested in the date, not the date and time

Comment: Of course the result is empty, unless you would happen to make this query one day later at the exact _second_ one of your entries has - you are comparing for _equality_ here. Have you been tricked by the word INTERVAL into thinking that this would create an actual interval with a starting and ending time for comparison …? That’s not what INTERVAL does, no.

Comment: @CBroe Interesting point you have there! Is there any work-around?

Comment: Well you don’t want to compare for _equality_, but …? Which other forms of comparison are there …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

will return only yesterday date as `2017-09-19 13:39:09`

So surely this will return empty results only as per your table records.

If you want today records means, try like below,

```
SELECT * FROM q_lab.auto_profile_status_log WHERE apsl_timestamp BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND NOW();
```

may this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * FROM q_lab.auto_profile_status_log WHERE apsl_timestamp = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```